Stein's Real Analysis Chapter 4 Exercise 16
I'm having a trouble with the exercise 16 in chapter 4 of Stein's "Real Analysis, Measure Theory, Integration, Hilbert spaces".

Let $F_0(z) = 1/(1-z)^i.$
(a) Verify that $|F_0(z)|\le e^{\pi/2}$ in the unit disc, but that $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to1}F_0(r)$ does not
exist.

[Hint: Note that $|F_0(r)| = 1$ and $F_0(r)$ oscillates between $\pm1$ infinitely often
as $r\rightarrow1$.]

(b) Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and let
$$F(z) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\delta^jF_0(ze^{-i\alpha_j})$$
where $\delta$ is sufficiently small. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to1} F(re^{i\theta})$ fails to exist whenever $\theta = \alpha_j$, and hence F fails to have a radial limit for a dense set of points on the unit circle.

(a) is OK, but I'm having trouble with (b). It looks to me that $F(z)$ does NOT fail to exist. Here's what I attempted.


When $\theta = \alpha_k$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$,
$$F(z) = \delta F_0(re^{i(\alpha_k-\alpha_1)}) + \delta^2 F_0(re^{i(\alpha_k-\alpha_2)}) +... + \delta^k F_0(r) + \delta^{k+1}F_0(re^{i(\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_1)})+...$$
where all terms including $k^{th}$ term will vanish as $r\to 1$ because by (a) all $F_0$ is bounded and $\delta^j$ is  sufficiently small regardless of the oscillation in $k^{th}$ term.

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Existence of the limit of each term does not say that the limit of the infinite sum exists.

Thanks for your comment! Hmm, that’s true. But then how can I prove $F(z)$ fails to exist? I’m guessing $k^{th}$ term has some clue, but because of $\delta^k$, $k^{th}$ term also seems to disappear.
